# how to pass auth token fetched by axios to cy.visit in cypress test

Tags: react-native, cypress

I am writing e2e tests using cypress to test our react app. In the spec file, I have following code in the beforeEach,

```
describe("My Test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit(
      `/?token=${authToken}&testing=1`
    )
  })
...
}
```

I need fetch the authToken from another url and the token is expired every hour. I have following code using axios in a separate file:

```
import axios from "axios"

export const getAuthToken = () => {
  const data =...
  const url = `https://.../oauth2/v2.0/token`
  const config = {
    method: 'post' as const,
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: data
  }

  return axios(config).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return (response.data["access_token"])
  })
```

But I am not sure how to call getAuthToken in the beforeEach?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is just Javascript, so you can import and use the function (if it's in a file under `/cypress` folder and not part of the `/src`).

```js
import { getAuthToken } from 'path/to/file/with/getAuthToken'

describe("My Test", () => {

  beforeEach(async () => {   make this hook async so we can await
    const authToken = await getAuthToken()
    cy.visit(
      `/?token=${authToken}&testing=1`
    )
  })

}
```

If it's part of the app `/src`, you may not be able to import it.

An alternative is to attach a reference to window

**App**

```js
import axios from "axios"

export const getAuthToken = () => {
  ...
}

if (window.Cypress) {
  window.getAuthToken = getAuthToken 
}
```

**Test**

```js
describe("My Test", () => {

  beforeEach(() => { 
    const getAuthToken = cy.state('window').getAuthToken  // get reference
    getAuthToken().then(authToken => {
      cy.visit(
        `/?token=${authToken}&testing=1`
      )
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the async way, I do get the auth token, but I got following error on the next command: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > cy.visit()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > cy.customCommand()

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.

Comment: `async/await` seems to be incompatible with Cypress. Try it with `.then()`.